# Upload a file to Azure Blob storage using Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

How to upload a file to Azure Blob storage using Azure Java SDK and also print the timestamp after uploading the file?

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-java-stable

Answer (score 1):

***I tried in my environment and got successfully uploaded file with timestamp in azure blob storage:***

**Code:**

```
package  com.blobs.quickstart;
import  org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch;
import  com.azure.storage.blob.*;
import  com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;

public  class  App
{
public  static  void  main( String[] args )
{
String  connectStr = "< Connection string >";
BlobServiceClient  blobServiceClient = new  BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();
String  containerName = "test";
BlobContainerClient  containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
String  localPath = "path of your file";
BlobClient  blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient("barcode.docx");
StopWatch  watch = new  StopWatch();
watch.start();
System.out.println("\nUploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t" + blobClient.getBlobUrl());
blobClient.uploadFromFile(localPath);
watch.stop();
System.out.println("Time Elapsed: " + watch.getTime());
}
}
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli

Comment: do we need to install something because for BlobServiceClient Iam getting error

Comment: Hi @chopss what error you are getting? also you need to include dependency azure storage blob in pom.xml

Comment: You need to use POM.xml file because pom.xml is Maven configuration file and controls the build process for the project. web.xml is web application configuration file.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.azure.core.util.CoreUtils.getDefaultTimeoutFromEnvironment(Lcom/azure/core/util/Configuration;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/time/Duration;Lcom/azure/core/util/logging/ClientLogger;)Ljava/time/Duration;
 at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder.<clinit>(NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder.java:70)
 getting this error....my main function is also loading when I put the below line it shows error there                .....BlobServiceClient  blobServiceClient = new  BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();

Comment: Could you raise in new question i will answer there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74518525/problem-while-uploading-from-local-to-blob-storage....added here plz..check ...i have wriiten main fuction in correct format,,,,but something wrong with connection string line