# Problem while uploading from local to blob storage

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage

I tried to copy a file from local to blob storage but its showing error in a specific line which I'm not able to figure out.

Here's the code:

```java
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();
String containerName = "test-db";

BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);

BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(values);

System.out.println("\nUploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t" + blobClient.getUrl());
blobClient.uploadFromFile(localPath+values);
```

And this is the message I get:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a one-stop-code-shop, nor is it a place where you can dump code and hope someone fixes it. Please have a look at the [tour] and see if you can create a [mcve].

Comment: Mention the code in code format not in images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60589689/the-exception-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-thrown-when-invoking-azure-storage-rel

Comment: -no......Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.11.327:

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

**Code:**

```
package com.blobs.quickstart;
import com.azure.storage.blob.*;

import  com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;
public  class  App
{
public  static  void  main( String[] args )

{

String  connectStr = "< Connection string>";
BlobServiceClient  blobServiceClient = new  BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();
String  containerName = "test";
BlobContainerClient  containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
String  localPath = "C:\\Users\\v-vsettu\\Documents\\Venkat\\barcode.docx";
BlobClient  blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient("barcode.docx");
blobClient.uploadFromFile(localPath);
System.out.println("File uploaded!!!!");
}
}
```

Please follow the [MS-DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell,managed-identity,roles-azure-portal,sign-in-azure-cli) to start java with azure blob storage. you will get pom.xml using document instruction.

**Pom.xml:**
In pom.xml file you need add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
       <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
      <version>12.10.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

**Console:(pom.xml)**

[image]

**Console(Output):**

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]
In portal the local file is uploaded successfully to azure blob storage portal.

Comment: i used same code but same error is coming again

Comment: i used the above code but the problem still persists,,,...may be some issue with dependency

Comment: Check the dependency of azure blob storage and give the correct version.